# If the paths of .sh file and linux c file are different, then how to use the system command? Seen one ans. on stackoverflow but not clear

Tags: c, bash, shell, path, sh

I have a `.sh` file, say `B.sh`, that calls `goal.c` (a Linux C file), and `goal.c` calls `A.sh`. The paths of `goal.c` and `A.sh` are different.

Upon being called by `goal.c`, `A.sh` produces some output which will be seen in the same directory as that of `A.sh`.  But I do not see anything as a problem occurs in `goal.c` calling `A.sh` using the system command.

I used as the system ("Pathname of A.sh"), but a warning comes as, system() ignored and I feel the command is not executed.

How do I use the system command in this case?

Comment: Are you running the C files without compiling them first?

Comment: Please show the code and show the exact warning message.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided simple examples of these 3 files that exhibit the concern. As written, I'm having trouble understanding what your question is, and how you are executing your `.c` program since you haven't mentioned compiling it.

Comment: How to reply to the comments I got for my above post? I am new here so I am writing under comment. As asked by mttpgn and lurker, I did not compile the c program. I directly ran the B.sh which in turn invokes goal.c prg and this invokes the A.sh. But now I will first compile goal.c and then run B.sh. Thank you.